# Master and Subproblem for Column Generation Algorithm

Tags: linear-programming

Let $S$ be a set of vectors defined as $S := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ : e^Tx = 1\}$.  A vectorization of matrix $xx^T$, denoted by $vec(xx^T)$, is a transformation by stacking the columns of $xx^T$ on top of each other, resulting a column vector. Given inputs $q \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times {n^2}}$, and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, the problem is as follows:

$\min q^Ty \\
s.t. Ay = b \\
y \in Conv\{ vec(xx^T) : x \in S\}$

My approach is to solve the problem with Column Generation Algorithm. However I am not sure how to set up the master and the subproblem of the main problem above, especially with the existence of the last constraint. 
I will really appreciate any help!

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you learn about the column generation algorithm? Can you suggest any references to learn more about it?